# HTML: ZIP file download from server issue

Tags: php, html, apache, server

I'm sorry about my tittle. I'm not sure how I can categorize this question.Please do edit if necessary-Thanks

Here is the issue I'm having:

http://domain.com is my main server- in this main server I'm listing all of the downloadable files I have from another server which is http://myfilehost.com.

on http://domain.com I list my files like so:

```
<a href="http://myfilehost.com/downloads/myfile.doc">download myfile document</a>
<a href="http://myfilehost.com/downloads/myfile.zip">download all myfile</a>
```

The first link is working perfectly fine but when it comes to the zip file I always get the ff error which is really weird:[image]

Here is the htaccess of http://myfilehost.com which I think is the default of wp as its also a wp website not sure if this is hosted on hostgator/bluehost:

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

**And o I think this is also worth mentioning:**
When I try to go to http://myfilehost.com first and wait for it to load then add the directory */downloads/myfile.zip*  to the URL its actually working perfectly and downloading myfile.zip..

Thank you Everyone for your kindness of helping me and giving me a response

Comment: Are you on wireless by any chance? ps, who's the host for your domain? And can you also update your question with any `.htaccess` file you have (*if you have one*)?

Comment: nope I'm not on wireless.. http://myfilehost.com is actually a wordpress site i forgot to mention.. let me add the htaccess

Comment: added the htaccess

Comment: not sure I really understand whats wrong with it try adding the download tag to your a-href link, like this; `<a href="http://myfilehost.com/downloads/myfile.zip" download>download all myfile</a>`

Comment: @LewisDay I am aware of download attribute.. I actually tried it however for some reason download is failing too.Failed -  Network error